# How to terminate a vba script before an application on time schedule in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script which runs when workbook opens, where I have set some times like the following

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:00:00"), "MasterMacro"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:30:00"), "MasterMacro"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:00:00"), "MasterMacro"

End Sub
```

There is a case where the script MasterMacro is not finished till the next run.. so how can I stop it before then next?

Comment: Two and a half hours is a long time for a macro to run. What's it doing?

Comment: Trivial web scraping eventhough python would be better idea

Comment: Arrange additional `OnTime` events prior each `MasterMacro` call event, and call a sub with the only line `End` to force running code termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with a flag accessible from both caller and callee, like this:

```
Private IsRunning As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    IsRunning = False

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:00:00"), "MasterMacro"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:30:00"), "MasterMacro"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:00:00"), "MasterMacro"

End Sub

Sub MasterMacro()
    If IsRunning Then
        Debug.Print "Is already running. Aborting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Debug.Print "Starting Master macro"
    IsRunning = True

    'Lengthy operation
    'goes here

    IsRunning = False
End Sub
```

**Different approach**
If the master macro tests if a termination is requested inside its loop, it can abort the loop and allow for the next run of the master macro

```
Private TerminationRequested As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    TerminationRequested = False

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:00:00"), "MasterMacro"

    TerminateLongRunningOperation
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:30:00"), "MasterMacro"

    TerminateLongRunningOperation
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:00:00"), "MasterMacro"

End Sub

Sub TerminateLongRunningOperation()
    TerminationRequested = True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")
End Sub

Sub MasterMacro()
    TerminationRequested = False

    For i = 1 To 10000
        If TerminationRequested Then Exit Sub

        ' One of many iterations
        ' goes here

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: After writing this, I realized that you asked for something different - how to stop the running operation, rather than aborting the coming one. The concept is the same, but you will have to put the test inside your lengthy operation instead.

Comment: What do you mean by test the if condition? if isrunning...lenghty operation... end if?

Comment: @Nikos - I added a different approach

Comment: `TerminateLongRunningOperation` is called twice at the `Workbook_Open` event. Not just before 10:30 or 13:00. Have you tested the code before posting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example showing how you can terminate running code prior to `OnTime` event call.

Put the below code to `ThisWorkbook` module:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "EndlessLoop"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:08"), "TerminateRunning"

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:11"), "EndlessLoop"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:18"), "TerminateRunning"

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:21"), "EndlessLoop"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:28"), "TerminateRunning"

End Sub
```

Put the below code to a standard module:

```vb
Sub EndlessLoop()

    Do
        Cells(1, 1) = Timer
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub

Sub TerminateRunning()

    End

End Sub
```

Note you have to distribute `DoEvents` statement consistently across your code so that the events take effect instantly.